# Concatenar log.i con un textview

Tags: android, android-studio

Es posible concatenar un textview con un log para que me muestre el valor de este en el log? Es decir si se puede crear una variable y esta enviarla al log para que muestre el valor del textview que esta recibiendo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **[edit] tu pregunta** con el código que estés usando para lograr lo que expones en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para añadir mas información a la respuesta de Curro, te muestro diferentes tipos de log con sus posibles utilizaciones.

```
 Log.e(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de error");
 Log.w(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de warning");
 Log.i(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de información");
 Log.d(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de depuración");
 Log.v(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de verbose");
```

A la hora de concatenar, puedes hacer dos cosas:

***Concatenas directamente obteniendo el resultado del TEXT en el mismo log como bien ha explicado el compañero Curro.***

```
 Log.e(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de error" + txtView.getText().tostring());
 Log.w(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de warning" + txtView.getText().tostring());
 Log.i(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de información" + txtView.getText().tostring());
 Log.d(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de depuración" + txtView.getText().tostring());
 Log.v(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de verbose" + txtView.getText().tostring());
```

***O guardas el contenido del texto en una variable y asi es mas sencillo de ver.***

```
// Guardamos el texto de tu TextView en la variable de tipo String textObtenido 

 String textObtenido = txtTexto.getText().ToString()
 Log.e(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de error" + textObtenido);
 Log.w(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de warning" + textObtenido);
 Log.i(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de información" + textObtenido);
 Log.d(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de depuración" + textObtenido);
 Log.v(LOGTAG, "Mensaje de verbose" + textObtenido);
```

Imagen para que lo veas en funcionamiento:

[image: Logs en funcionamiento]

Espero que te sirva !

Comment: Gracias! pero a que te refieres con txtTexto en la variable, me gustaria hacerlo con la variable para hacerlo mas sencillo.

Comment: txtTexto es como he llamado hipoteticamente a tu textView. Puedes llamarlo como quieras. el formato es (nombre del textView.quiero su texto. conviértelo en String) 'txtNombredetuTextView.getText().ToString()'

Comment: Gracias, ya funciona!

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede y ademas muy simple:

```
Log.e("DEBUG_LOG", "Mensaje de error " + tutextview.gettext().tostring());
```

En vez de Log.e puedes usar el tipo de log que te interese, ese es un ejemplo.

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: y si el textview lo invoco desde un fragment? tambien se puede?

Comment: es una chorrada pero el metodo es`getText()` con mayuscula ^^ y tambien el `toString()`

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, pero si tu pones el log en el codigo del fragment, no tienes problema ninguno en llamarlo, pero si el log lo estas llamando desde el activity entonces si que no puedes acceder a el asi como asi. Coloca el codigo en el fragment y veras como si que funciona.

Comment: Si, lo he colocado en el fragment, me dice que getText(int) in fragment cannot be applied. Log.i("debug", "*****************************0" + frag.getText().toString()); eso es lo que tengo

Comment: Escribe la traza completa del error por favor, para saber exactamente que es y la linea de codigo donde te da el error.

Comment: getText(int) in fragment cannot be applied to (). y yo tengo esto para que lo muestre Log.i("debug", "*****************************0" + frag.getText().toString()); y  frag.temp(data.value(Float.class).toString());